# Infinite arithmetic progression with no perfect powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Is there an infinite arithmetic progression with no perfect powers?

---

I think the answer is yes, and I tried to construct one such sequence to prove the existence. The first thing I thought of was something like $1+2^k, 1+2^{k+1} , 1+ 2^{k+1} + 2^k,....$ but I couldn't show none of these are actually any perfect powers. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are such infinite arithmetic progressions. For example, consider one with a starting value of $a = 2$ and a common difference of $d = 4$. If the terms are $t_k$, for $k \ge 1$, we then have

$$t_k = 2 + 4(k - 1) = 2(1 + 2(k - 1))$$

Note that $1 + 2(k - 1)$ is always odd, so every $t_k$ will always have exactly one factor of $2$. This means no $t_k$ term can be a perfect power, i.e., of the form $n^m$ with $m \gt 1$, since $n$ has to be even, but then $n^m$ would have more than one factor of $2$.

More generally, any infinite arithmetic progression is an example if, for some prime $p$ and using the [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) function, the first term $a \gt 1$ has $\nu_{p}(a) = 1$, and the common difference $d \gt 1$ has $\nu_{p}(d) \gt 1$.